# WSO2 Send mediator and/or Inbound Endpoint SMB (CIFS)

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, esb, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Quite new to the product, but looks promising. Can someone explain me two things:

1. How do I parse credentials to an SMB inbound enpoint. I have a remote share, but I do not want the BUILTIN guest account to be enabled nor want to grant network BUILTIN account access (so everyone can just hit the share). I tried smb://user:password@host/share/folder but that didn't work.
2. How do I point a send mediator correctly to an SMB end point? I get something like "The system cannot infer the transport information from the \host\share\folder URL", the URL I set as endpoint in the send mediator.

Comment: I can get it to work with Proxy services, but I understood that in a cluster config, proxy services cannot be coordinated, so multiple WSO2 servers start polling the same directory which results in trouble. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll need to enable VFS transport sender/receiver in axis2.xml (otherwise you'll get can't infer transport... error) More [info here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/VFS+Transport).

Then, you can connect to smb quite similar to ftp. There's a specific sample [available here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB460/Sample+265%3A+Accessing+a+Windows+Share+Using+vfs+Transport) as well. You'll be able to define the credentials inline in the url.

In addition, if you use ESB 4.8.1 or older version, and poll the same vfs location with multiple nodes, there can be locking/concurrency issues. This is solved in new ESB 4.9.0 with [File Inbound endpoints](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/File+Inbound+Protocol) that support distributed locking.